# Slice Method regarding the return of a certain amount of letters in an array

Tags: arrays, methods

I have a question regarding the .slice() method:

Use the slice method to return the word "bananas".

```
var txt = "I can eat bananas all day";
var x = txt.slice(10, 17); //This doesn't make sense...why 10 and 17?
```

So: are they counting letters in the sentence? Because the letter 'b' of the  word bananas is the 7th in the array...so how can it be 10?

Comment: It is the 10th letter. You seem to have miscounted. The 7th letter is the "a" in "eat".

Comment: How are you counting that? Just curious...I am starting at "I" which is 0...?

Comment: For the start of each word, I is 0, c is 2, e is 6, and the b in banana is 10.

Comment: If you know Python, `list(enumerate("I can eat bananas all day"))` gives `[(0, 'I'), (1, ' '), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'n'), (5, ' '), (6, 'e'), (7, 'a'), (8, 't'), (9, ' '), (10, 'b'), (11, 'a'), (12, 'n'), (13, 'a'), (14, 'n'), (15, 'a'), (16, 's'), (17, ' '), (18, 'a'), (19, 'l'), (20, 'l'), (21, ' '), (22, 'd'), (23, 'a'), (24, 'y')]`, which shows the indices of each letter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Much appreciated. :) I was coding in JavaScript...

Comment: Don't forget that spaces also count toward letters.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

string index starts from 0. That means the first character in the string is at index 0.

In a string every space is counted too.

So that means in your string, the first letter 'I' is the 0th element. Now start counting from 'I'. The space next to 'I' is at index 1. And continue counting indexes.

First parameter of Slice(a, b) will point to that exact index in the string(that is ath index) and the last parameter will point to the one index before that(that is b-1th index).

In your case first parameter is 10. So the 10th index is storing 'b'.

17th index has a space stored in it. But it'll point to 16th index which has 's' stored in it.

the index number for bananas are written down,

```
'b' - txt[10]
'a' - txt[11]
'n' - txt[12]
'a' - txt[13]
'n' - txt[14]
'a' - txt[15]
's' - txt[16]
```

[Have a look here for more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)